# Qt Signals and Slots sending arrays of structures

Tags: c++, arrays, qt, data-structures, signals-slots

I am looking to send data that varies in size (depending on number of tracking markers). I have a structure designed to hold all the info for one marker. This I then need to send via signals and slots to another thread to be processed. I have added the necessary meta type declarations for the structure to work. I have connected all the signals and slots properly and have everything working for one structure. However when I try to send arrays of markers the signal is not sent/recieved. Why can I only send singular instances of the structure not arrays of them, even though the structure its self contains an array??

I have tried signal and slot definitions such as:

SLOT:

```
void update(Datastruct output[])
```

and 
SIGNAL:

```
void updatemarkers(Datastruct&)
```

Here is my structure:

```
#ifndef RETURNSTRUCT_H
#define RETURNSTRUCT_H

struct Datastruct
{
    int markerid;
    double markererror;
    double markertrans[3];
    double markerrotation[3][3];

};

Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(Datastruct);

#endif //RETURNSTRUCT_H
```

this line was  also included to avoid inferring a namespace with the type declaration.

```
// after QApplication was instantiated
qRegisterMetaType<Datastruct>("Datastruct");
// but before any class is instantiated that connects signals with this type
```

Why can I only send singular instances of the structure not arrays of them, even though the structure its self contains an array??

I am using windows 7, MinGW 32bit, Qt 5.7.0, Qt Creator 4.0.3

Comment: You're using C++, not C, using a C-style array usually has no place in C++ code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using Qt data structures instead of a simple array. Something like [QList](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlist.html) or [QVector](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvector.html). They are already a metatype and can be sent by default through signals and slots.
Let me know if it works.

Comment: And you can take care about threading when you use such containers. Maybe an interesting article about Qt-data structures: http://blog.qt.io/blog/2009/08/25/count-with-me-how-many-smart-pointer-classes-does-qt-have/

Comment: Okay: I am not trying to use any pointers as the data is generated to fast and memory is overwritten or reallocated before it is processed by my other thread ( I have tried) I have now attempted to use the QVector template to contain a vector of my structure but simply nothing happens, I do not get any errors/warnings I just don't get my data at the other end :(

Comment: Whats the point in using QVector this way. Also it doesn't have to be a pointer. You can pass the whole vector or a reference to it.

Comment: Is it not possible to dereference the data and send a complete copy of the array of my structure? (sorry this was not clear before)

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the question, but yes you can. Signals and Slots work as a normal C++ function. If you allocate the QVector on the stack (not with new QVector()) it is passed by copy.

Comment: Just don't use a reference in the signal. Am I missing something?

Comment: @LucaAngioloni No you are right, maybe another little hint... i wouldn't use signals to give all the information to another method, especially in case of big data structures like lists, it doesn't feel good in my opinion. I would give an hint that there are some new data available and rethink about my data structure.

Comment: Okay so QVectors now work, (seems I needed to brush up a little) as for whether I should only use sig/slots to alert to new data and actually store the new data in some shared buffer, the data is not enormous, max about 50-60 doubles, nothing larger. I had tried with the buffer but it is a bit overkill when this works fast enough to capture all the data. Thanks for all the help though.